# How to pass arguments from UFT to command line

Tags: command-line, cmd, vbscript, command-line-arguments, hp-uft

I am trying to run tests in UFT by running a .vbs file. I am also passing arguments through command line. .vbs file reads the arguments and sets the environment variable of UFT. Hence, I can read them inside UFT.

```
qtApp.Test.Environment.Value("First_Argument") = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
qtApp.Test.Environment.Value("Second_Argument") = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
```

After that, I want to get a number as an output from UFT because I will use that output to pass it to the next command in command line.

Comment: What number do you want to return?  Any number?

Comment: `WScript.Arguments.Count`?

Answer (score 0):

The Test Parameters Object can be a way [, more detailed in the Automation Object Documentation](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/all/AutomationObjectModel/Default.htm#QuickTest~Parameter~Modify%20the%20Value%20of%20a%20Test%20Parameter%20in%20a%20Parameter%20Collection_E.html)

You will have to define the TestParameters of the TestCase from the UFT IDE(manually) there is no way to define them automatically. If you declare them as in and out type, and change their value as a part of a Test Case, you would be able to read it afterwards from the vbs (Do not open a new Test Case until you did not read out the preferred values)

Although this is a working (and standard) way for exchanging parameters between the driver script and the TA Robot(UFT) **I would advise you to use a simple file based way of doing this** - managing test parameters can be very time consuming.

Tell the script via an Environment variable the path of the xml / json or simple text file where you expect the results to be written and when the test is done, read the content of the file (assuming the test will write into that file)

The plain old file way should not be underestimated especially in such circumstances.